# How to get data from API and insert it into database without repeating in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

So, I have simple web application that takes data from api, deserializes it, inserts it into database and then displaying it in a table.
I don't know how to separate deserialisation and insertion from my Index() method, so every time I refresh the page it deserializes and inserts data again.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private DBContext db = new DBContext();
    public string data = "...."; //here is the json data that i get from API

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        RootObj myData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObj>(data);
        foreach (var item in myData)
        {
            MyModel myItem = new MyModel
            {
                name = item.name,
                symbol = item.symbol,
                price = item.price,
            };
            db.MyItemsDB.Add(myItem);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return View(db.MyItemDB.ToList());
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

How can I separate deserialisation and insertion from Index() method?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't think about that my json is changing, but it does and because of that I need to do the insertion into database with every page refresh. The solution is doing unique field in the database, so there will be no repeated data.

**UPD:** The field "name" of myItem must be unique, but I need to update data in other fields if the item with this name already exists, so I did this:

```
db.MyItemsDB.AddOrUpdate(m => m.name, myItem);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Hey Quid, I'm not sure if this is considered an answer, only if you know how to work with the unique field in a db.
If you need help finding out how to set up the unique field in a db, you could edit your original answer.

Comment: @JorenVandamme hey, I updated my answer, you can check if it's correct now.

Comment: Great! 
If you think that solves your question, you can mark your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do a database insertion per unique user, you could use a cookie.

If the cookie doesn't exist, the user didn't visit the site yet (or has deleted his cookies)
If the cookie exists, the user already visited and you don't do the database insertion.

It doesn't remove all the insertions, but it reduces them.

```
If(HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("myCookie") == false)
    db.SaveChanges();
else 
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = new HttpCookie("myCookie");
    myCookie.Value = "SomeInfo";
    myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1d);
    Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming the db.SaveChanges() is the database insertion you are talking about.

Comment: db.SaveChanges() is the database insertion I'm talking about, yes. But it's not per user, it just takes the json file, deserializes it and then does the insertion of that data into database. Web application is supposed to show that data in the table then. The problem is that I need the deserialization and insertion to happen only once.

Comment: Is there anything unique in the json so you can check if it already exists in the db?

Comment: Yeah. I think you're talking about doing unique fields in the database and I actually thought about doing this, but I came to conclusion that it's not a good way to solve this problem. Is it so? Or is there no other way?

Comment: Is the JSON always the same? I'm kind of confused on why you would get it, and then only save it once.

Comment: Oh, thanks, now I see. The thing is I thought that there is no reason to do insertion with every page refreshing, but if the json is changing there actually is. Sorry for the confusion, I just didn't get it. The thing with unique database fields is the solution, I guess.

Comment: Yeah, you could use a unique fields, check if the json is already inthere and add if it's not inthere.
It could just take "a lot" of time.